# Paperclip/Amazon S3/Heroku avatar picture gone missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

In the navbar, the user's profile picture is missing.

[image: site]

This is the link of that image:

http://stynyl.com/avatars/nav/missing.png

Not sure what to post here. All the other images on my site work perfectly. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure the image is actually available? It doesn't load for me

Comment: Hey @RichPeck . Not sure what happened on the site or what I changed, but the avatar works now. Have you visited the site and tried to upload an avatar on registration?

Comment: Nope lol - I just clicked your link & it said "We're sorry something went wrong"

Comment: Ah. Haha. Would you mind taking a look at this question? It's about my failing ActiveAdmin install. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307766/invalid-route-name-already-in-use-admin-root-argumenterror-failed-active

@RichPeck

Comment: I'm not too experienced with ActiveAdmin right now unfortunately :( I think you've attracted someone who is though!

Comment: Alrighty. @RichPeck . Thanks anyway :D My site's really coming along. I've done quite a bit since we last spoke.

Comment: Nice! I told you it would be better!